# Getting 'error while loading shared libraries' when using -L to specifically find the library

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors

I've been trying to solve this for a few hours now. 
I am compiling some c files using gcc. The files require libpbc, so I am using the -L flag to point gcc at the directory which contains libpbc.so.1. The code compiles without error yet when I attempt to run it I get the following error message:

> ./example.out: error while loading shared libraries: libpbc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Looking at similar questions this error message seems to indicate that gcc can't find libpbc.so.1. I know gcc sees libpbc.so.1 because when I rename libpbc.so.1 to something else it fails to compile.

I am using -L to point to the directory which contains libpbc.so.1.

Not sure what next steps I can take to figure this out. Would appreciate any ideas. What does this error message mean exactly?

## EDIT

Running ldd example.out results in:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7fe3000)
libpbc.so.1 => not found
libgmp.so.3 => /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3 (0xb7f87000)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ldd example.out
```

That will give a lot of useful information about dynamic linking. More specifically though, your problem most likely lies with the path of the library not being in.

```
/etc/ld.so.conf
```

Note, that if you update that file, you must then run

```
ldconfig -v
```

Comment: Do I need root to update that file? I want to static link this library.

Comment: ls -l /etc/ld.so.conf to see its permission.  It's usually only writable by root.

If you want to statically link the library, that's a completely different topic.  Everything in my post was about dynamic linking.

If you want to go static, use the -static argument to gcc.  There are numerous gotchas that come along with static linking as it doesn't always do what you think it's doing. :)

Comment: Yes, static linking seems to have broken everything =(

Comment: Is there anything else (other than -L and -I) I should be providing to 'gcc -static' so that is can find the libraries?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725472/static-link-of-shared-library-function-in-gcc

He said it better than I would have.

Answer (score 4):

Provide **rpath** flag while compiling.

```
g++ -Wall -o example.out -I ./include/ -L ./examplelibPath -Wl,-rpath ./libPath -l examplelibrary example.cpp
```

Comment: I used `-Wl,-rpath .` and it solved my problem. Short, sweet, easy. Simpler than editing the /etc/ld.so.conf file.