# Creating a portable cross distro php cgi binary

Tags: php, compilation, portability

I'm after creating a php5-cgi binary to run on most of the linux distros.

I know there are lots of text about these but none of them leading anywhere.

I don't want to use ermine.

These guys compiled one but doesn't work on 64bit systems. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-magento-on-a-php4-server

So I can see it's possible. Just need to know HOW! :)

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are after (mixed 32/64bit binaries won't work), but for example static linking might help with distribution-independence a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725472/static-link-of-shared-library-function-in-gcc