# Cannot find -lgpg-error

Tags: g++, makefile, ld, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I am doing a project for which I need to compile a source code. The code uses the PBC library (which in turn needs the GMP, both of which have been installed). The Makefile has this line :

```
node: node.o $(COMMON_OBJS)
g++ -m32 -g -static -o $@ $^ -L../PBC -lPBC -lpthread -lgnutls -lpbc -lgmp -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -ltasn1 -lz
```

But when I run make, I get this error :

```
/usr/bin/ld : cannot find -lgpg-error
```

Now this is quite frustrating as I don't know how to fix it. I tried installing libgcrypt11-div (saw a suggestion on some site). Didn't work.

I noticed that libgpg-error.so is installed in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/. So I created link with ln -s in /usr/bin/. Still not working.

After adding the -v switch :

> `g++ -m32 -g -static -o node node.o application.o networkmessage.o usermessage.o buddy.o buddyset.o systemparam.o bipolynomial.o polynomial.o lagrange.o commitment.o commitmentmatrix.o commitmentvector.o io.o timer.o message.o -L../PBC -lPBC -lpthread -lgnutls -lpbc -lgmp -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -ltasn1 -lz -v`
>
> `Using built-in specs.`
>   `COLLECT_GCC=g++`
>   `COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/lto-wrapper`
>   `Target: i686-linux-gnu`
>   `Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,go --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu`
>
> `Thread model: posix`
>   `gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)`
>
> `COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/
>   LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../i386-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/:/lib/i386-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/`
>
> `COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-m32' '-g' '-static' '-o' 'node' '-L../PBC' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'`
>   `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/collect2 --build-id --no-add-needed --as-needed -m elf_i386 --hash-style=gnu -static -z relro -o node /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/crtbeginT.o -L../PBC -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib -L/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../.. node.o application.o networkmessage.o usermessage.o buddy.o buddyset.o systemparam.o bipolynomial.o polynomial.o lagrange.o commitment.o commitmentmatrix.o commitmentvector.o io.o timer.o message.o -lPBC -lpthread -lgnutls -lpbc -lgmp -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -ltasn1 -lz -lstdc++ -lm --start-group -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc --end-group /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o`
>   `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgpg-error`
>   `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`
>   `make: *** [node] Error 1`

Comment: Can you add the `-v` switch to gcc/g++?

Comment: Did you add the switch? You should see the version of gcc/g++ and the library search path among other things.

Comment: I ran sudo ldconfig -v | grep gpg

'/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu' given more than once

/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/i386-linux-gnu' given more than once

/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu' given more than once

 libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.8.0

 libgpgme-pth.so.11 -> libgpgme-pth.so.11.7.0

 libgpgme.so.11 -> libgpgme.so.11.7.0

 libgpgme++-pth.so.2 -> libgpgme++-pth.so.2.8.0

 libgpgme++-pthread.so.2 -> libgpgme++-pthread.so.2.8.0

 libgpgme-pthread.so.11 -> libgpgme-pthread.so.11.7.0
 libgpgme++.so.2 -> libgpgme++.so.2.8.0
'

Comment: And what if you try it without the `-static` switch?

Comment: Looks like the package you need is `libgpg-error-dev`. Making your own symlink in `/usr/bin` is never a good idea.

Comment: @slm Wonderful. Thanks , that did the trick. The code has compiled succesfully.

Comment: @tripleee I had already installed **libgpg-error-dev** but it still hadn't worked. Though I think I should remove the links from /usr/bin/. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to `-static` you need to wrap it around libraries that you want to be static and let the other libraries remain dynamic, otherwise gcc/g++ will try and go down into every library and compile everything statically which may not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `-static` switch.

If you want to -static you need to wrap it around libraries that you want to be static and let the other libraries remain dynamic, otherwise gcc/g++ will try and go down into every library and compile everything statically which may not be possible.

See this SO post, [Static link of shared library function in gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725472/static-link-of-shared-library-function-in-gcc).

For example to compile applejuice statically while everything else remaining dynamic:

```
gcc object1.o object2.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lapplejuice -Wl,-Bdynamic -lorangejuice
```