# Statically linking to dynamic library (Wintel)

Tags: dll

I've grown increasingly tired of dll's. Is there a straightforward way to
extract obj files from a dll, or otherwise statically link to a dynamic library?

Comment: Extraction: no. Inclusion: [asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725472/static-link-of-shared-library-function-in-gcc).

Comment: that answer seem to only apply to linux

Comment: GCC (MinGW, actually) works on Windows too, so you might just want to try it out.