# c++ libraries linking and creating

Tags: c++, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I'm using libraries a, b, and c to create library x. I want to give library x to my friends without them Having to have libraries a, b, c. I've tried .so files and .a files but .so crashes before first line of main and .a requires libraries a, b, and c. Using ubuntu g++ and c++11

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is compile your library X link libraries a, b and c Staticly.

This answer should point you in the right direction.
[Static link of shared library function in gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725472/static-link-of-shared-library-function-in-gcc)

Comment: So something like `g++ -la -lb  -lc -o X.so source.cpp`?