How to include a .so library within an executable?
I have a simple C++ application that requires the use of a very small system library libunwind.so.1 file (37KB). After successful building, whenever the libunwind.so.1 is moved, the executable produces the error:
./hello: error while loading shared libraries: libunwind.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This is my CMakeLists.txt file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project(converter)

# The library is in this folder:
link_directories(/path/to/lib/libunw STATIC)

target_link_libraries(converter PUBLIC /path/to/lib/libunw/libunwind.so.1)

add_executable(converter ${CMAKE_AR} main.cpp)

How can I include this library within the standalone compiled output so that if the folder /home/user/Documents/libunw is moved, the compiled runner remains working?

So, do you want your hello executable will find libunwind.so.1 even after it is moved into other location? In that case you need to specify appropriate RPATH for your executable. See e.g. that wiki about setting RPATH in CMake.

Thanks. Is it possible to integrate libunwind.so.1 statically inside?

No, you cannot integrate a shared library into the executable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725472/static-link-of-shared-library-function-in-gcc

Not sure if you still need the solution.

Populate the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH (environment variable used in Unix and Linux systems to specify a list of directories where shared libraries are searched for first) with the path /path/to/lib/libunw
in cmake add statement- target_link_libraries(main libunwind.so.1)

